# Simple DOM - scraping a site with missing classes

Tags: html, arrays, class, dom, screen-scraping

I am scraping a classifieds' site and each page has 15 listings for the search results. Most vehicle listings will have class=price for the price. However, there are some listings that omit a price which means my array of 15 can be missing values and that's a problem when I later loop through them to display the listings on my site. So how can I ensure that each array value is populated? Here is an example of the HTML from the site that I'm scraping:

```
<div class="search-results">
    <a class="inner">
        <div class="desc">Vehicle 1</div>
        <div class="desc">Vehicle 2</div>
        <div class="desc">Vehicle 3</div>
        <div class="desc">Vehicle 4</div><div class="price">$30,000</div>
        <div class="desc">Vehicle 5</div>
        ...
        <div class="desc">Vehicle 15</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is my code which works if there are prices for each listing, but fails if any are missing:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="search-results"] a[class=inner] div[class=price]') as $a) {
    $car_price[] = $a->plaintext;
}
```

This code only returns one array value in this example and it's not even in the 4th position of the array because it's the only value in the array. So how can I ensure that all 15 array elements have a value, even if the price is null? My thought was to create a null value if it's missing but I'm not sure how to do that. Thank you!